# Are resource request questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Questions like [this one](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/380/is-there-an-online-resource-that-show-which-languages-share-the-same-alphabets) are requests for resources that can help them in some way, as long it is related to learning/teaching another language. There seems to be confusion (as seen in the comments) whether these types of questions are on topic or not.

So are resource request questions on-topic for our site? This is not a duplicate because this is requesting resources, not methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are methods recommendation on-topic?](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/27/are-methods-recommendation-on-topic)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe

Comment: You need to specify "on-topic" on the meta site. Per my comment on the linked item, a resources list is a compilation of resources available to support users of that site. Because this would be off-topic on a main site, meta is the place to keep it. Then it is easy to point to when such request is received (even though such questions would be off-topic, it may help the OP).

Comment: @Quill: Method recommendations and resource requests are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource requests can fit on SE, as long as they're objectively framed.

> Does *Resource X* exist?

Should be fine.

> Can you recommend a *Resource X* that you like?

Clearly isn't fine.

---

I don't see your sample question as particularly problematic--and apparently neither does the community at large. At the moment it's +1/-1, with no close votes.

It's not an especially strong question, though, but IMO, that's not because it's asking for a resource.  The question's weakness, in my mind, comes from the fact that it's not well researched, as evidenced by the two built-in misunderstandings: 1) Languages share alphabets, 2) All writing systems use alphabets.

Also, the fact that Wikipedia has a list, which is mentioned in comments, suggests that the OP didn't research their question very thoroughly.

But even these perceived weaknesses didn't earn my down vote or my VtC.

Comment: Different from "that you like", which is clearly subjective, how about something like "Is there a *Resource X* that will help me learn Mongolian parts of speech?" Here the request is not based on personal preference but objective requirements/qualities of some resource that may or may not meet the OP's requirement.

Comment: @user3169; I'm not sure that's much of an improvement, at least in many cases. See some related discussions [here](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/29/13) and [here](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/155/13).

Comment: Those seem to ask opinions. I am talking about objective qualities of various possible solutions.

Comment: @user3169: "Can X accomplish Y?" may be objective, in the strictest sense. But it's not very meaningful. a) It's a yes-or-no question. b) It may be that X *can* accomplish Y, but it may be very cumbersome or difficult to do so. These are the reasons such questions are generally better to avoid.

Comment: @user3169, as I read this again two months later, I think you're on to something, I just take issue with your specific suggested wording, which focuses on subjective outcomes rather than objective intentions. "Is there a *Resource X* that focuses on Mongolian parts of speech?" would seem good to me.