# Why was 'Are there books or resources in Spanish for learning Latin with 0% experience?' closed?

Tags: discussion

Being objective, [my question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/467/90) consists with [this answer](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/162/90) which specifies:

> Resource requests can fit on SE, as long as they're objectively framed.
>
> > Does Resource X exist?
>
> Should be fine.

Comment: Also, I don't know many people learning Latin through Spanish. A problem with this question is that it's super specific and probably will be unapplicable or unhelpful to any future visitors to the site. This is one really localized situation.

Comment: @li12 What about all Hispanophones who study Latin?

Comment: True, but there is a significantly higher number of people learning Latin through English, German, or French than there is Spanish. One reason for this is that it's mostly scholars that tend to study Latin, and the primary language of communication between scholars is English.

Answer (score 8):

Answering a question like that with "yes" or "no" wouldn't be very helpful, so I suspect what you are actually asking for is a list of those resources.

Read the rest of that [answer you linked](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/are-resource-request-questions-on-topic/162#162) above. This site is designed to ask very *specific* questions that can be answered authoritatively and *definitively* in the space of the post. Asking broadly for a list of resources to pick through later isn't really a great question in the context of this site. Read the section of my answer under [potentially dozens of answers, all valid](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/1).

> **Potentially dozens of answers, all valid**
>   The hallmark of a good Q&A site is the best-constructed, "correct" answer rises the top. If the top answer (or the top few) don't complete the issue being asked about, that is neither definitive nor authoritative. Questions soliciting suggestions, recommendations, anecdotes, or polling of the community aren't generally a good fit for this site.

Folks can start answering randomly and something useful *might* be tossed in the mix, but that defeats the purpose of voting to assure the *best,* most-correct answer rises to the top.

This [comment on your question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/467/are-there-books-or-resources-in-spanish-for-learning-latin-with-0-experience#comment848_467) is asking why anything found in that Amazon search would not work for you. It seems to be guiding you towards a more specific question that can be answered in the space of a post — an answer that is both authoritative and *definitive* in the context of this site.

That's why the question, as asked, was closed as too broad.